# How to save checked value/state from radio button in an Html page form to custom list in sharepoint online 2013

Tags: list, javascript, sharepoint-online, content-type

I have a working loop that finds all the input tags in a Html form.
My problem is that it wont save what state the radio button are in to the custom list in SharePoint online. I have other loops for option and choice input that gets saved like it should, and the same goes for a loop of text area.

All of the input tags are `type="radio"` except for one that are `type="text"` and a date "and that one gets saved".

In the Custom list in SharePoint online.
The radio button should be saved in a column with Yes/No checkbox and the default value for that are no if not checked to be yes.

```
*** in the App.js file

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  $(document).tooltip();
  $("#btnSave").click(createListItem);
  $("#GEN_4").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val();
});


function createListItem() {
 listCreationInformation = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation(); 
 listItem = list.addItem(listCreationInformation);

 var input_list = $('input');

 var id, name, text;

 for (var i = 0; i < input_list.length; i++) {
     name = $(input_list[i]).attr('name');

     if ($(input_list[i]).attr('type') === 'radio') {
         //text = $(input_list[i]); //this code should be added to in some way!

          // I have tried these versions, and none of them will work.

         // text =$(input_list[i]).is(':checked');
        // text = $(input_list[i]).prop('checked');
         //text = $(input_list[i].checked('type') & 'radio');

     }
     else {
         text = $(input_list[i]).val();
     }
     listItem.set_item(name, text);
  }
  listItem.update(); //Update the List Item
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, success),
    Function.createDelegate(this, fail)
   );
 }

***in the aspx page

   <td>GEN_19_BYGG_GOLV</td>
   <td id="GEN_19">
       <input name="GEN_19" type="radio" value="1">Ja
        <br/>
        <input name="GEN_19" type="radio" value="0">Nej
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need to loop. You can get the input element using jQuery Selector.

In case of radio button use following to identify if its selected or not

```
if($('#radio_1').is(':checked')) {
    //Save Yes
}
else {
    //Save No
}
```

Update the HTML as follows

```
<td>GEN_19_BYGG_GOLV</td>
<td id="GEN_19">
   <input id="radio_1" name="GEN_19" type="radio" value="1">Ja
    <br/>
    <input id="radio_2" name="GEN_19" type="radio" value="0">Nej
</td>
```

**Updated based on comment**

```
$('input[name=GEN_19]:checked').val()
```

The above will give you the value of selected radio button who is in the group "GEN_19"

Comment: It's not the solution I'm looking for. 
if it was only one radio button there would be no need for the loop, but now it's 14 radio buttons in a larger form. 
The grouping by name ensures that only one can be selected simultaneously by those who have the same name. 

My problem is that the value from the radio button I choose are not saved from the form to the custom list in SharePoint.
Please help!

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that worked!
Using .prop('checked') and setting the listItem in both if and else.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < input_list.length; i++) {
    name = $(input_list[i]).attr('name');

    if ($(input_list[i]).attr('type') === 'radio') {
        if ($(input_list[i]).prop('checked')) {

            text = $(input_list[i]).val();
            listItem.set_item(name, text);
        }
    }
    else {
        text = $(input_list[i]).val();
        listItem.set_item(name, text);
    }
  }
```